# Flash AS3: How to Resize a Rect within another Rect?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I've got a tricky one that's stumping me, could you take a quick look over it please...

I draw a rectangle within another rectangle like this (I use it as a mask):

```
CanvasBorder.graphics.beginFill(0xf0ff00,0.1);  
CanvasBorder.graphics.drawRect(100,100,550, 300);
CanvasBorder.graphics.drawRect((stage.stageWidth/2-Canvas.width/2),(stage.stageHeight/2-Canvas.height/2),250, 150);
CanvasBorder.graphics.endFill();
```

effectively its a 550x300 box with a 250x150 cutout.

Within one of my functions I need to resize the INNER 'cut-out' box from 250x150 to 150x100 - but keep the OUTER box exactly the same.

Normally when I'd resize a normal rectangle I'd do this:

```
rectangle .width = 150;
rectangle .height = 100;
```

But this solution doesn't work and I don't know how to reference the cutout of the shape. Any ideas please I'm really struggling with this one and can't find anything on google.

thanks for your time

ChainsawDR

Comment: solved via another forum. need to clear the graphics and readd.

CanvasBorder.graphics.clear(); 
CanvasBorder.graphics.drawRect(100,100,550, 300);
CanvasBorder.graphics.drawRect((stage.stageWidth/2-Canvas.width/2),(stage.stageHeight/2-    Canvas.height/2),150, 100);
CanvasBorder.graphics.endFill();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create ANOTHER `Sprite` or `Shape` like this:

```
// somewhere in your code declare the rectangleMask
var rectangleMas:Shape;


rectangleMask = new Shape();
// draw the rectangle the same way
// and add it to CanvasBorder (I assume that CanvasBorder is a DisplayObjectContainer)
CanvasBorder.addChild(rectangleMask);
```

Then you can just do the resize as you want:

```
rectangleMask.witdth = 150;
rectangleMask.height = 100;
```

If you want that rectangle to be a mask of CanvasBorder you can do this:

```
CanvasBorder.mask = rectangleMask;
```